# Unable to have full screen Ubuntu in VirtualBox

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, fullscreen, guest-additions

I am  trying to install ubuntu 14.2.16 on VirtualBox. It has installed correctly, but I was having a problem related to window size. It is not possible for me to switch ubuntu in full screen mode. I got some solution for that i.e. installing Guest Additions. But afterwords I got error: unable to mount C:program files/oracle/VirtualBox/GuestAssitions.iso
For that i got one solution.([Unable to mount the CD/DVD image on the machine Sandbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/321589/unable-to-mount-the-cd-dvd-image-on-the-machine-sandbox))
I followed all steps given by but as it says about VBoxLinuxAdditions.run file, it should be executable. But file I am having in my host PC is not executable. I even checked settings in file property, its type is program still not executable, its opening in text editor.

What should I do now? Even if anybody could suggest me different solution for switching it in full screen it would be really helpful.

Comment: Not quite sure if you've got a Windows host and Ubuntu as the VM or the other way around.  If Ubuntu is the VM, then VM run a terminal (in the VM) and make sure you install Guest Additions using "sudo .VBoxLinuxAdditions.run".  You will likely find the .ISO in /media or /mnt.  Otherwise, if Windows is the VM, as you said, ensure the .exe for the Guest Additions has the execute bit set.

Comment: Actually Windows is host and ubuntu is VM. But my real problem was with full screen size of window in VBox. I got rid of that problem by scaling window size.But resolution of ubuntu is set by default on 640x480 via built in display. Option to change resolution is not there. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 4):

Installing Virtualbox guest addition from terminal did the trick for me.

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11
```

Comment: Installing `virtualbox-guest-x11` got it to run for me with `Kubuntu 20.04`

Answer (score 2):

`sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-x11`

As of 'unable to mount' problem, you can insert `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxGuestAdditions.iso` file into virtual CD/DVD manually, and them mount  `/dev/cdrom` device to a folder of your choice (`mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/mycdfolder`).

Comment: Remember that this installation needs to be performed on the guest system. This should fix the fullscreen problem and even improve performance.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue running a Virtualbox on a Macbook Air. Here is what I did to remedy the problem.

Update your system to the latest packages:

```
apt-get update -y
apt-get upgrade -y
apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

Then reboot

Then install all the dependencies by running the following command:

```
apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Then reboot again.

Load the VirtualBox guest additions CD. Create a folder and copy the files from the CD to your Hard drive. I copied everything even though I probably didn't have to.

Then chmod 755 VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
reboot and it should work.

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you've installed VirtualBox Guest Additions. In the window of the guest VM, check the bottom right for a line of icons. The icon second from the right, looks like a blue egg at an angle and a green arrow to the right. If you hover your mouse over that, the tooltip will tell you if Guest Additions is installed.

If Guest Additions is not installed, then you must install it if you want do things like change the video resolution. See [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html) for more background. Remember to use `sudo` before any command when installing/running, which the link I gave does not use in all places.