# How to include VirtualBox GuestAdditions when Ubuntu server is guest on Windows host?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, windows

I've been trying to share a folder on a Windows 10 host with an Ubuntu server VirtualBox guest. Without any success. This answer to this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1347212/accessing-shared-folder-on-virtualbox-6-1-windows-10-host-ubuntu-20-04-serve) looked promising but failed at

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sr0 /cdrom
mount: /cdrom: mount point does not exist.
```

Host: Windows 10 Pro, 22H2 Build 19045.3930
Guest: Ubuntu Server 22.04.3 updated & upgraded to date

Surely there's some additional magic required. but what?

Here are some selected lines from VBox.log in a freshly built guest VM. The lines were taken after noting that Devices had already chosen the guest additions iso.

VBox.log excerpt:

```
00:00:49.320576 VMMDev: Guest Additions information report: Version 6.0.0 r127566 '6.0.0'
00:00:49.320633 VMMDev: Guest Additions information report: Interface = 0x00010004 osType = 0x00053100 (Linux >= 2.6, 64-bit)
00:00:49.320829 VMMDev: Guest Additions capability report: (0x0 -> 0x0) seamless: no, hostWindowMapping: no, graphics: no
00:00:49.321030 GUI: UISession::sltAdditionsChange: GA state change event came, notifying listeners
00:00:49.321150 GUI: UISession::sltAdditionsChange: GA state change event came, notifying listeners
00:00:51.431218 GUI: UISession::sltAdditionsChange: GA state really changed, notifying listeners
00:00:51.431266 GUI: UISession::sltAdditionsChange: GA state change event came, notifying listeners
00:17:20.664248 GUI: UISession::sltAdditionsChange: GA state really changed, notifying listeners
00:17:20.664350 GUI: UISession::sltAdditionsChange: GA state change event came, notifying listeners
00:17:40.092446 VMMDev: Guest Additions information report: Version 6.0.0 r127566 '6.0.0'
00:17:40.092896 VMMDev: Guest Additions information report: Interface = 0x00010004 osType = 0x00053100 (Linux >= 2.6, 64-bit)
00:17:40.093165 GUI: UISession::sltAdditionsChange: GA state change event came, notifying listeners
00:17:40.093562 VMMDev: Guest Additions capability report: (0x0 -> 0x0) seamless: no, hostWindowMapping: no, graphics: no
00:17:40.093747 GUI: UISession::sltAdditionsChange: GA state change event came, notifying listeners
00:17:40.127555 GUI: UISession::sltAdditionsChange: GA state really changed, notifying listeners
00:17:40.127607 GUI: UISession::sltAdditionsChange: GA state change event came, notifying listeners
00:25:19.300129 File system of 'C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso' (DVD) is ntfs
00:25:19.301531   Path      <string>  = "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso" (cb=58)
```

Comment: @zwets Amazingly, this is the first time I've seen that command. Walking the wrong alleys, must be. Now all I need to do is stumble on the right command to get permission on the folder contents.  `sudo chown -R george:vboxsf /media/sf_diet` doesn't do the trick. Regardless, I'd happily accept your comment as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that running:

```
apt install virtualbox-guest-utils
```

in the guest may do just what you want.